# asp.net file upload blank image files

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have written some code for saving an image to a folder in asp.net. My problem is that the image in the folder is white and is not the same as images added manually to the folder.

[image]

I used a simple asp.net fileupload control to save the file to the correct path. But the images dont display on the page and this is how the file icons look in visual studio.

Anybody know why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Because it is not included as part of the project files.

Try this:

[image]

There isn't anything else that is wrong. Only the files are not tracked by VS, so they won't be published. **Your files are still completely accessible from your code.**

In my opinion, files like say images added to your web app shouldn't be part of the project.

Answer (score 2):

Try Right-clicking the images and select "include in project"

**edit**

If you want to do that programmatically you need to modify the project file programmatically; that's all there is to it. It's an XML file with nothing special about it. Note, however, that you have this under source control and you'll probably need to do more than just modifying the project file (ie adding the file to source control too)

Comment: Ok that works but is there anyway to do it programmatically because I have built an image cms. The whole point of the cms is that the user can modify one of the pages.

Comment: @nickgowdy you can still access your files from your code. What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: When I include the new images as part of the project they are not visible on the actual page itself. I figured not being part of the project was the reason why but it could be something else. I will accept your answer because it solved my initial question.

Comment: @nickgowdy yep it's most likely something else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include them in the project by right clicking them and click `Include In Project`.

Furthermore, if you want these files to included in the build you need to go to `Properties` of each file and set `Build Action` as `Content`.